# M2epro- quantity in magento and amazon is not same

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

M2epro installed in Magento site and we are selling products in amazon. We are receiving order details from amazon to magento order. M2epro cron runs every minute. The issue is the quantity in magento and amazon is not same. I assume M2epro not updating quantity when some sales happen in amazon and vice versa. Please help us to fix this issue.

Comment: which m2e version are you using at the moment?

Comment: we are using 5.2.1.r4422

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem on version 6 something. It took forever and several support tickets to get this working.

Edit your Synchronization Templates:
First change them to advanced view.
Under Configuration

select List Rules
change List Conditions QTY:* to more or equal and Quantity:* to 1.

Select Relist Rules
change Relist Conditions QTY:* to more or equal and Quantity:* to 1.

select Stop Rules
change Stop Conditions
Stop When Status Disabled:* to yes
Stop When Out Of Stock:* to Yes
Stop When QTY Is:* to Less or Equal
Quantity:* to 0

What the big deal is some times in Magento you can have a negative number like QTY: -2 and M2E Pro will list it as 2 in-stock, Also sometimes you have a QTY of 0, but still have in-stock set, so M2E Pro will list it as in stock. This is all on M2E Pro side, but I find Amazon does not always update in a timely manner. You need to lower you update frequency to longer then 15 minutes or the updates just stay in a state of update and never complete.I have mine set to every 30 min.
Good Luck James Niland
Niland Enterprise LLC